# Error with compiler while trying to run FEniCS example code

Tags: c++, python-3.x, fenics

I've just tried to install FEniCS on Ubuntu 16.04 and when I try to run the first example code using python3.5 I get the following 2 errors:

```
 RuntimeError: Expecting a string or list of strings, not
 {'slepc_real', 'sz', 'mpi', 'mpi_cxx', 'hdf5', 'boost_timer', 'm',
 'boost_filesystem', 'z', 'dolfin', 'petsc_real', 'dl'}.

 RuntimeError: Unable to compile C++ code with dijitso
```

[image: image of error attached]

Has anyone encountered this and managed to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

the problem, in this case, is an old version of `pkgconfig`. Please update it with the command

```
$ pip3 install -U pkgconfig
```

Then, this problem should disappear even without your changes in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dolfin/jit/jit.py`

Comment: great, I did not know about this `pkgconfig`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem just now.  I ran the ran tutorial with the python debugger:

```
$ python3 -m pdb ft01_poisson.py
```

I found the problem and fixed it (hackishly) by adding the explicit cast to list with the added list(...) statement on three lines /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dolfin/jit/jit.py

```
# Set compiler/build options 
params = dijitso.params.default_params() 
params['build']['include_dirs'] = list(dolfin_pc["include_dirs"]) 
params['build']['libs'] = list(dolfin_pc["libraries"]) 
params['build']['lib_dirs'] = list(dolfin_pc["library_dirs"])
```